# Set-cookie then redirect using Python and HTML

Tags: python, html, cookies

I'm using the Cookie library in Python.

I'm trying to Set-cookie then redirect the user to another page, say "http://example.com".

This is how I set the cookie:

```
cookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
cookie["session"] = random.randint(0,1000000000)
cookie["session"]["domain"] = ".bla.net"
cookie["session"]["path"] = "/itzhaki/"
print "Content-type: text/plain"
print cookie.output()
logging.debug(' Cookie set with: '+cookie.output())
```

I tried to drop the "Content-type: text/plain" header, but this is the only way it actually sets the cookie.

For redirection I tried to use:

```
print "Location: http://example.com"
```

But that only gives me a 500 server error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Add a blank line after the headers.

```
...
print cookie.output()
print # <------------
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But the answer was the exact opposite lol :) Only when I dropped the blank line after cookie.output() it finally worked.